# Java source compilation failed - Cassandra Function

Tags: java, cassandra, user-defined-functions

I am new to Cassandra and I am trying to create a User Defined Aggregate but stuck at function creation.

Data in table is -

```
count| host
-----+-----------
 102 | test_host1
 100 | test_host2
 101 | test_host2
 101 | test_host3
 104 | test_host3
 101 | test_host1
 100 | test_host3
 103 | test_host3
 102 | test_host3
 100 | test_host1
```

The function that I am writing will count that how many rows are there in my table with a particular host. If I provide test_host1 to the aggregate, The desirable result will be 3.

Find below function's code -

```
    CREATE FUNCTION countSessions(dataMap map<text,int>,host text)  
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT  
    RETURNS map<text, int>  
    LANGUAGE java as  
    ' 
    Integer countValue = dataMap.get(host); 
    if(countValue == null) { 
    countValue = 1; 
    } else { 
    countValue++; 
    } 
    dataMap.put(host,countValue); 
    return dataMap; 
    ';
```

On Executing this on cqlsh, I am getting below error -

> InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Could not compile function 'visitors.countsessions' from Java source: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.InvalidReq
>   uestException: Java source compilation failed:
>   Line 2: dataMap cannot be resolved
>   Line 7: dataMap cannot be resolved
>   Line 8: dataMap cannot be resolved to a variable
>   "

I am not able to understand what sent wrong with my function's code. Please help.

Plus, can someone suggest me any link/site (Other than datastax) using which I can properly understand UDFs and UDAs.

Thanks and regards,

Vibhav

PS - If anybody chooses to down-vote the question, kindly do mention the reason in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not working because `dataMap` is being converted to lower case in the initial declaration. You can either do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION countSessions("dataMap" map<text,int>,host text)  
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT  
RETURNS map<text, int>  
LANGUAGE java as  
' 
Integer countValue = dataMap.get(host); 
if(countValue == null) { 
countValue = 1; 
} else { 
countValue++; 
} 
dataMap.put(host,countValue); 
return dataMap; 
';
```

or

```
CREATE FUNCTION countSessions(datamap map<text,int>,host text)  
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT  
RETURNS map<text, int>  
LANGUAGE java as  
' 
Integer countValue = datamap.get(host); 
if(countValue == null) { 
countValue = 1; 
} else { 
countValue++; 
} 
datamap.put(host,countValue); 
return datamap; 
';
```

to make this work.